# fields from 2 datasets in one matrix

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, dataset

I've got 3 datasets from which I get data from in my rdlc report. The problem is, is that I need to show data from 2 datasets into one table or matrix. I've already got a join/relation on the two tables from which I need the data, but I can't add the column of a second dataset. How do I do this?

My query to show data looks like this:

```
    private DataTable getData(string invoiceNo)
    {

        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        dtable.TableName = "dtNewDataSet_Table";
        string sql = "";
        sql = "SELECT * FROM [SOS].[dbo].[StockControlOrderNumbers] SON " +
              "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[StockControlOrders] SCO " +
              "on SON.StockControlOrderRef = SCO.ID " +
              "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[StockControlBaseStock] BS " +
               "on SCO.VendorNo = BS.VendorNo " +
              "WHERE [OrderNo] = '" + orderNo + "'"; 

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(dtable);
        DataTable dt = dtable;
        return dt;
    }
```

The matrix will only have 3 columns - vendor, description(these two from StockControlBaseStock) and orderQty (from StockControlOrders). The vendor and description is shown in the matrix, but I need to show the OrderQty of that item as well.... Any ideas on how to do this? These two tables are joined with the vendorNo....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about .Net DataSet and DataTable objects? Are you getting the data from an RDLC or from a SQL query?

Assuming you have queried your data into two data tables you can do the following:

- Put both data tables into a data set
- Add a DataSet.Relation to create Primary and Foriegn keys on the two
  DataTables
- Loop through the tables to get your joined columns, or use a data
  table view

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeskbwf7(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeskbwf7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.relations(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.relations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)